# Missing Script Files?

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to use the ANT Landscape, and the item does not show in the Mesh object list. I went to the user preferences and saw this:
[image]

I unchecked the box and tried to check it again, and got this:
[image]

I also uninstalled Blender and reinstalled it. Same problem.

I'm using a 64-bit PC, Windows 7, 8Gb RAM.
Blender version: 2.79

Help?

Regards,
2Hawks